# error after delete item from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I try remove `this` item from array in database on click button, but I got errors, I can't see my mistakes. I have error: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded and what's more important I have `/api/editProduct/undefined`

factory:

```
    userFactory.deleteDescription = function(description) {
    return $http.delete('/api/editProduct/' + description)
}
```

api

```
    router.delete('/editProduct/:description', function(req, res){
    Product.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body_id }, { $pull: { description: this }}, function(err, product){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(!product){
            res.json({ success: false, message: 'No user found' });
        } else {
            console.log('ok')
        }
    });
});
```

model

```
    var productSchema = new Schema({
title: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
},
level: {
    type: String,
    require:true,
},
description: [{
    type: String,
    require: true,
}],
});
```

[image]

The piont is remove chosen item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use named parameters in your expressjs routes, you can access the value via `req.params['yourKey']`. in your case this would be `req.params.description`

so for you to remove a description entry within one of your Products, you can do

```
Product.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: req.body_id },
    { $pull: { description: req.params.description }},
    function(err, product){
        ...
    }
);
```

Comment: And req.params.description is equal undefined

Comment: are you sure you are calling your api correctly? because in your question, you say you call `/api/editProduct/undefined` .. which means the value of `req.params.description` is a string with a value of 'undefined', not equal to `undefined`.
try calling it with `/api/editProduct/someDescription`

Comment: Everything seems work better, but req.body_id return undefined